# Mongoose - Aggregation $match based on enum values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation with mongoose, the objects what i get looks like this:

```
foods: {
  fruits: {
    apple: 'NONE',
    banana: null,
    pearl: 'INCLUDED'
  }
}
```

The fruits can have 4 values: null, 'NONE', 'INCLUDED', 'EXTRA'

My goal is to make the $match/filter in this aggregation, to be able to filter out the null and 'NONE' values.

Is there any option to do this?

Like at the aggregation i have this:

```
    {
        $match: 'foods.fruits.pearl',
    }
```

Then get back those objects where the pearl have 'INCLUDED' or 'EXTRA' value?

Comment: What exactly should your result document look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb **3.4.4** and above

Well you have unknown keys here having value with `NONE` and `null` and therefore, you can use [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) aggregation to make keys into values and can easily [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with them

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "data": { "$objectToArray": "$foods.fruits" }
  }},
  { "$match": { "data.v": { "$in": [ "NONE", null ] } } },
  { "$project": { "data": 0 }}
])
```